# Wso2 APIM - Error while renewing Access Token for Consumer Key hXXXXX8a and user admin

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a working API on APIM in a linux box.

I am now trying to set it up in azure env with Linux installation. I had to do following additional changes in this new box.

> 1) has certificates applied
>   2) changed  in carbon.xml to box's hostname.

I am getting below error while regenerating access token in store.

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error
 while **renewing Access Token for Consumer Key hXXXXX8a** and user admin
 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
 org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred
 while calling token endpoint: HTTP error code : 500    at
 org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken_aroundBody10(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:383)
    at     org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:304)
    at    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken_aroundBody26(APIConsumerImpl.java:1019)
    at     org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.renewAccessToken(APIConsumerImpl.java:998)
```

Any pointers on what's could have gone wrong here? thanks

---

ETA - 
I am talking about APIM 2.6.0 here which is running on a Azure node.  I see two IP addresses associated to VM APIM is running on

```
Public IP address:11.22.333.444
Private IP address:10.240.0.98
```

My understanding is private is for internal communication between azure and is not visible to outside azure node. 
BUT I also see that Curl and Request URL in store is pointing to private IP address

**Curl**

```
curl -k -X POST "https://10.240.0.98:8243/AAA/1.0.0/getDevice" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 7647ce6f-51a5-3e59-b400-36ca9e458913" -d "{ \"DeviceIDStruct\":{ \"Manufacturer\":\"\", \"OUI\":\"00E0FC\", \"ProductClass\":\"HG5678\", \"SerialNumber\":\"U7D8W168888\" }}"
```

**Request URL**

```
https://10.240.0.98:8243/AAA/1.0.0/getDevice
```

This is probably causing the issue as Private IP address is not visible outside Azure node.

Comment: What APIM version are you using here? And are we talking about the all-in-one setup or a distributed one?

Comment: both systems have 2.6.0, Its not a distributed system

Comment: There should be more logs stating the reason for above 500. Please post those as well.

Comment: @Bee -- There is no more info in logs than what i have put in above. I have also Added more info under main query above. \n

[2019-12-16 15:01:51,937] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error while renewing Access Token for Consumer Key hKVE9Fzjtbo_spZIvfaHkJT3E48a and user admin {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while calling token endpoint: HTTP error code : 500